# Well-urned balls

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

You want to maximize the number of red balls you get. Any red ball you draw you may keep. Any green ball you draw ends the game.

- Urn A contains one red and one green ball. You just draw.
  You get an expectation value $E(A)=1/2$ ($p=1/2$ you get the red and draw the green,
  $1-p=1/2$ you immediately draw a green one).
- Urn B also contains one red and one green ball, but if you draw
  the red one, another red goes into B. You can do the infinite
  sum in your head, the expectation value is $1$ ball.
- Urn C contains two balls, where the content is equidistributed over the number of red balls. This means with $p=1/3$ both balls are red and you get both, with $q=1/3$ both are green and you get none, and with $1-p-q=1/3$ it contains one red and one green as in A,
  giving a red ball with fifty-fifty chance again. Makes $(2+0+1/2)/3=5/6$ balls.
- Urn D is like C, but has the first ball being red with $p=1/2$ and the other too.
  You get both red balls with $p=1/2*1/2=1/4$, none with $q=1/4$ and a half
  with $1-p-q=1/2$. Makes $3/4$ balls.
- Putting back would make no sense for C and D, since with finite probability
  you have only red balls and the expectation value thus is $\infty$.

Observe $E(A)<E(D)<E(C)<E(B)$. Is this true generally for Urn A and B containing $n$ red and $n$ green balls, Urn C $2n$ balls equidistributed over the number of red balls and Urn D as C, only having each ball the probability $p=1/2$ that it is red? (I sorta doubt it, the advantage of Urn B gets close to zero with large $n$.) Please give general formulae for any $n$.

Comment: What is "Eric Half-A-Ball"?  Why do you have "half" in C and D?

Comment: @Henry: A compulsory Monty Python reference. The sillyness policeman edited it out. Also made the description more precise: C and D contain 2 balls in any case.

Comment: I still not see why you have "half" in C and D as an alternative to $2$ and $0$.  Why is it not $1$, making their expected number of red balls each $1$?

Comment: @AlvinL with Urn A, the expected number of red balls drawn is $\frac12 \times 1+ \frac12\times 0=\frac12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just suppose there are $r$ red balls and $g$ green balls.  We draw, without replacement, until we get a green ball, and we count the number of red balls we had drawn.  This has expected value $r/(g+1)$.  (*Sketch*: Use the usual trick by summing indicator functions corresponding to whether each red ball is drawn, and note each red ball is drawn before all the $g$ green balls with probability $1/(g+1)$)

Applying this to the general case of $n$ (except for $B$, where the analysis is identical to that of two balls), we have

$$E[A] = \frac{n}{n+1} \\ E[B] = 1 \\ E[C]= \frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\frac{r}{2n-r+1}$$ and $$\begin{align*}E[D] &= \frac1{2^{2n}}\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r} \frac{r}{2n-r+1} \\ &= \frac1{2^{2n}}\sum_{r=1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r-1} \\ &= \frac1{2^{2n}}\left(2^{2n}-\binom{2n}{2n}\right) \\ &= 1 - 2^{-2n}\end{align*}$$

It is now not hard to see that $$E[A] < E[D] < E[B]$$ for every $n$.  The series for $E[C]$ is less nice, but we don't need to find a closed form for it to conclude.  Instead, we can just note that for $n\geq2$,
$$E[C] \geq \frac1{2n+1}\sum_{r=2n-1}^{2n}\frac{r}{2n-r+1} = \frac1{2n+1}\left(\frac{2n-1}2 + \frac{2n}{1}\right) = \frac{6n-1}{4n+2}$$ and therefore
$$E[C] \geq \frac{11}{10} > 1 = E[B]$$

Comment: Very nice, but I find it still unclear if for all $n$ the order on the quantities $E[A], E[B], E[C]$ and $E[D]$ is the same as in the original post. (Except of course that in all cases $E[A] < E[B]$.

Comment: Looks nice (I never heard of the indicator trick, but then, I'm no math pro) - any chance to simplify the sums? (I doubt it, such an ugly denominator...)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I've updated the answer.  The sum for $E[C]$ can be simplified, but it's still not as nice as the others.  Rather the nicest form I can give is $$E[C] = H_{2n+1} - 1$$ where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$ are the harmonic numbers.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: After a second look I also identified C with the harmonic numbers (and that C dominates D is clear since there are more "good" cases with more red balls) but the simplification for D was a nice surprise. (Which now begs the question if there is a more simple argument to derive the result for D.)